# Updating JLabel when JButton Clicked on from another class

Tags: java, swing

I want to update JLabel's text when clicking on JButton.
The problem is that they are on different classes.

I minimized my code as much as I can, so this code doesn't contain every code that I actually have.

Below is the 1st Panel's code, which contains a button that will trigger the text updating method.

```
public class CultureCategorySelectPanel extends JPanel {


    public CultureCategorySelectPanel(JFrame mf) {
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(1000, 600);

        JButton bookCategoryBtn = new JButton("Book");

        // When Clicking on JButton
        bookCategoryBtn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                mf.getContentPane().removeAll(); 

                CultureListPanel myPanel = new CultureListPanel(mf);
                mf.getContentPane().add(myPanel);

                String text = “This text will be shown”;
                myPanel.updateLabel(text);
                
                mf.setVisible(true);
                mf.repaint();
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

And the below is the 2nd Panel's code, which has a textLabel that will be updated.

```
private JLabel plzSelectLabel;

public CultureListPanel(JFrame mf) {
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(1000, 600);

JLabel plzSelectLabel = new JLabel(“This text soon be changed”);
        plzSelectLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        plzSelectLabel.setBounds(138, 89, 367, 34);
        rightPanel.add(plzSelectLabel);
// 'rightPanel' is on the top of CultureListPanel, I put plzSelectLabel on the panel called 'rightPanel'


}

public void updateLabel(String text) { 
        plzSelectLabel.setText(text);

    }
```

When I run, I got Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" **java.lang.NullPointerException** at com.kh.mini_Project.view.CultureListPanel.updateLabel(CultureListPanel.java:169) error.

I also tried with getter/setter but it shows the same error.

**EDIT**

The code below is MainFrame.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
   public MainFrame() {
      this.setTitle("--");
      this.setSize(1000, 600);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setResizable(false);

     this.getContentPane().add(new WelcomPage(this));
      
      this.setVisible(true);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

The Driver class is here.

```
public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame();
   }
}
```

Comment: The line 169 of CultureListPanel.java is >>   plzSelectLabel.setText(text);

Comment: yes, it is. The error says NullPointerException on plzSelectLabel.

Comment: Please note the **R** in [mre]. Where is `CultureCategorySelectPanel` initialized ? Where is `rightPanel` initialized ?  Why does `CultureListPanel` construct a `JFrame` (`JFrame mf = new JFrame()`) and also receives a reference to  a `JFrame` in the constructor  ?

Comment: See a runnable [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61585634/3992939)

Comment: I'm pretty confused because I see no problem about plzSelectLabel. When I run the app, every component works perfectly fine until I hit the bookCategoryBtn and found the label that hasn't changed. I simply want to know why the plzSelectLabel stays null though I send the text thru the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor defines a variable **plzSelectLabel** which has a local (constructor) scope. Therefor the class level variable (with the same name) will not be initialized hence the NPE.

Hint: read some information about variable scopes ;-)

Comment: I declared `private JLabel plzSelectLabel;` at the field of the 2nd panel and is it still a local variable?

Comment: So does your constructor JLabel plzSelectLabel... This statement does not initialize the class variable, only the one declared in the constructor.

Comment: I removed the JLabel in the method and declare and init at the same time at the field area and it works. Thank you.now I can go to bed it's 1AM here T.T